# How to solve Python TypeError: type not understood

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror, recommendation-engine

I am creating a recommendation system and when I run this code I'm getting an error:

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds    
# Singular Value Decomposition
U, sigma, Vt = svds(pivot_df, k = 10)
```

And I'm getting this error: "TypeError: type not understood".

What could be the reason for this error and how should I solve it?

Comment: Can you please provide more information on your pivot_dk. Type of object or shape. Normally your input should be a sparse matrix or LinearOperator. Also keep in mind the k should be lower than the dim of your matrix.

Comment: The pivot_df is a matrix.

Comment: if it is a matrix can you give us the example ? Also the shape or something to try and test

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Do check `type(pivot_df)` to ensure the type of the object. In a similar situation, when I did this it returned `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. To then convert to a matrix, I inputted `U, sigma, Vt = svds(pivot_df.to_numpy(), k=10)`.

Answer (score 0):

*svds()* takes a sparse matrix or an ndarray as input.
But what you are passing is a Dataframe. Check the type by using the below command.

```
type(pivot_df)
```

Hence, you need to convert the Dataframe to np.ndarray while passing it to *svds()*.

```
U, sigma, Vt = svds(pivot_df.to_numpy(), k=10)
```